# Apache Drill DFS Information_schema / Metadata

Tags: apache-drill

Is it possible in Apache Drill to see the DFS files in the Information_Schema?

according to the Website ("Starting in Drill 1.15, Drill returns files available for querying in file-based data sources. You no longer have to use the SHOW FILES command to explore these data sources. You can query the FILES table for directory and file information.") i should be able to see the files. but i only see views which i created.

Is there anything i have to do, in order to see the files?

AFAIK file metadata (columns) cannot be seen in the Information_schema, or is there a possibility to make them visible? e.g. specifing a Schema?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Apache Drill documentation you can see information about files by querying FILES table (select * from information_schema.`files` [https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-the-information-schema/]).

Regarding exposing file metadata into information_schema, Apache Drill does not support this for file based tables. Though such feature will be supported after Drill Metastore introduction which is aimed to be delivered in 1.17 / 1.18 releases. Please see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6552 for more details.

Comment: thank you, i was confused About Information_schema.tables and … files :) !